# Editing Image using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have to edit few image files using python. I have to open each image file, add few points at particular location & save the new edited image file(For fd my post-processing work).

Problem I am facing is:
 1) I could not resize my plot axis. My plot axis should be 0-1 on both x &y with out any loss in image quality.
 2) I could  not save the edited image file, only the original file is getting saved.

This is what I tried:

```
im = Image.open('vortex.png')
implot = plt.plot(im)
fig, ax= plt.subplots()
myaximage = ax.imshow(im, aspect='auto', extent=(0,1,0,1), 
                  alpha=0.5, origin='upper',
                  zorder=-2)
plt.implot([0.5], [0.5])
plt.show()
im.save("new","png")
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides some small problems with your code, it seems you're basing your work on a wrong assumption: that you can turn a image into a matplotlib plot.

An image [is simply a collection of pixels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics). While your brain interprets it as a plot, with a axis, and maybe a grid, you can't expect the computer to do so. You can't manipulate a collection of pixels as if it were a plot - it isn't.

You need to forget about matplotlib and use the image editing resourses of PIL.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the axis change, but the saving of the file, see this post: 
[Python Imaging Library save function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562519/python-imaging-library-save-function-syntax)

From the PIL Handbook:

```
im.save(outfile, options...)

im.save(outfile, format, options...)
```

Simplest case:

```
im.save('my_image.png')
```